# How to change syntax highlighting in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting

```
a = np.array([1,4,3]) 
b = np.array([2,-1,5]) 
a@b

df['A'].fillna(value=df['A'].mean())
df.fillna(value=df.mean())
```

For teaching purposes: I need to apply a special color in Jupyter Notebook for coding to differentiate them from variables:

- `a, b`: black by default, ok
- `1,4,3`: Green by default, ok
- `@`: Purple  by default, ok
- `np.array( )`: black >>> need to change it to a different
  color (blue).
- `'A'`: red by default, ok
- `df[ ]`: black by default, ok
- `.fillna(value=`: black >>> need to change it to a different color
  (blue).
- `.mean()`: black >>> need to change it to a different color (blue).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom syntax highlighting in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650535/custom-syntax-highlighting-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Even if it is a duplicate, that question doesn't have a viable/complete/clear answer, so the question remains open and in need of answering, and this version is more specific and clear.

Comment: I agree, anaconda is pretty opaque on this rather simple issue. Color is important in a work environment. Allowing for variation in an apps appearance is not (or shouldn't be) rocket science.

Comment: You have more optionality for colouring (in fact any customiation you require) when useing `jupyter` notebooks in `vscode`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the Jupyter rendering of python code formatting within a python code cell relies on specific CSS styles.

so:

```
pd.DataFrame(...)
```

`pd` has a CSS style `cm.variable` (`cm`stands for `codemirror`)
`DataFrame` has a CSS style `cm.property`

So the Jupyter notebook sees `pd.DataFrame`, it only sees `variable.property`.

see picture:
[image]

```
python: 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]
jupyterlab==3.5.0
ipython==8.6.0
```

This seems to indicate there is no distinction between class attributes, class methods, class properties, module attributes etc...

I think it is because the python code is parsed and styled within the HTML rendering.

Here is where the magic occurs
`<server>/static/notebook/js/notebook/js/codemirror-ipython.js`

and here:
`<server>/static/notebook/js/components/codemirror/` (and child dir/files (`<server>/static/notebook/js/components/codemirror/mode/python/python.js` ))

You will find all the parsing code there, which seem to only treat the code present **inside an (HTML) cell**. From what I see, there is little to no indication that the JS code is able to go down the imports/callgraphs to determine the precise nature of code tokens like an IDE would (say PyCharm).

sample:

```js
  var wordOperators = wordRegexp(["and", "or", "not", "is"]);
  var commonKeywords = ["as", "assert", "break", "class", "continue",
                        "def", "del", "elif", "else", "except", "finally",
                        "for", "from", "global", "if", "import",
                        "lambda", "pass", "raise", "return",
                        "try", "while", "with", "yield", "in"];
  var commonBuiltins = ["abs", "all", "any", "bin", "bool", "bytearray", "callable", "chr",
                        "classmethod", "compile", "complex", "delattr", "dict", "dir", "divmod",
                        "enumerate", "eval",
//...
```

Maybe we can see things this way : a Jupyter notebook is not really an IDE, it may be better seen as an HTTP page that sends string to a python console : page sends `print('foo')`, (interactive) console does something roughly equivalent of `python -c "print('foo')"` and some glue gets the results and sends it back to HTML.

Unless:

1. someone points to the precise configuration parameter for Jupyter server pages that I could not find
2. and/or Jupyter dev teams add a better parsing capability for HTML rendering,

**OP desire seems impossible to achieve.**
You may be able to change color styles to a custom one, but not enhance the parsing capability on the HTML notebook rendering side to be more precise.

But, within a specialized IDE that has supports for notebooks (say [PyCharm pro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html) (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#tool-windows which shows advanced debugging capability, which makes me think I'm right :)) or VS code (*ref needed*)), maybe things can be different since the IDE can have a visibility on the whole python install/modules codebase and has access to its specialized code parsing and rendering engine (which in this case basically replaces what the Jupyter JavaScript code does !).

---

> For teaching purposes

I think an actual specialized IDE is the go-to tool for such precise syntax highlighting for emphasis on the nature of each code tokens.
see PyCharm config for function calls:
[image]
where the style is inherited from:
[image]
(of course you can set your own global defaults or language specific defaults ... that depends on the IDE)